# Tensorboard Embedding with t-SNE

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

When I run t-SNE on my datasets (on smallest or bigger one) with tensorboard embedding , the app crash all the times (after thereabout 500 iterations). 
I can't re-run or stop the operation to change the parameters, the iteration number freeze and the other functionalities on embedding part crash also.

Anyone have the same problem ? 
Other curiosity is if I run on [online tensorboard embedding](http://projector.tensorflow.org) I have the same problem.

Comment: If you are able to create a small repro, please file a bug on our github issues page.

Comment: Done @drpng ! Tks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the browser. Initially I was using Safari and had problems in all tabs of tensorboard. Switch to Chrome solved the problem.